# Pandas - Trying to merge a grouped Dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe that is grouped based on a few columns, if I tried to use this Dataframe to merge with another Dataframe get an error

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Given below is how my Dataframe looks like:

```
emp_id,date,count
1001, 11/1/2018,3
1002, 11/1/2018,4
    , 11/2/2018,2
    , 11/3/2018,4
```

I am trying to merge the above Dataframe with the below:

```
emp_id,date
1001,11/1/2018
1002,11/2/2018
```

Expected output:

```
1001,11/1/2018,3
1002,11/2/2018,2
```

Update (on the merged df):

```
df_new = df.groupby(['emp_id','date']).agg({'date':'count'})
```

Comment: How looks your merge code?

Comment: @jezrael, I have updated the initial post of how I am trying to group the data frame

Comment: So I guess need `df_new = df.groupby(['emp_id','date']).agg({'date':'count'}).reset_index()`

Comment: @nixon, trying to join first df with the second df based on the emp_id and date